# Ошибка undefined symbol при подключении динамической библиотеки

Tags: библиотеки, g++

Пытаюсь реализовать динамическую библиотеку и подключить её в своей программе. Библиотека будет работать с ncurses, но не думаю, что ошибка связана с этим.

Исходник библиотеки lib.cpp:

```
#include "panel.h"

void win()
{
    initscr();
    PANEL* root_panel = new_panel(stdscr);
}
```

Исходник программы main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    void* library_handler = dlopen("./lib.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    if ( ! library_handler)
    {   
        std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    };  

    return 0;
}
```

Команды сборки:

```
$ g++ -ldl main.cpp -o main
$ g++ -fpic -c lib.cpp -o lib.o
$ g++ -shared -o lib.so lib.o
```

Результат выполнения:

```
$ ./main                              
./lib.so: undefined symbol: stdscr
```

gcc версия 5.3.0

Видимо нужно указать/изменить какие-то опции компиляции или компоновки, но не могу ничего нагуглить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При линковке нужно добавить

```
g++ -shared -o lib.so lib.o -lncurses++
```

Comment: Да, это я опять молодец, упустил при формировании примера. Но на мысль натолкнули: использую cmake/make, сейчас попробовал собрать с make VERBOSE=1, оказалось, что он не указывает при линковке библиотеки ­— не воспринимает команду set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-lpanel -lncurses"), буду разбираться. В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: Как обычно, спроси и сам поймёшь, в данном случае надо CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS :)